# how to quick load javascript in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

android webview take too much time to load javascript, whenever  change the orientation of device(if change portrait to landscape it maintain as it in portrait mode of webview then after some time it will goes in landscape and vice-versa ).

i handle onConfigurationChanged() but it take time to reload the contents.

Thanks in advance.